# How to assign a "% symbol" to decimal value - so that i can export the same in Excel sheet

Tags: c#

How to assign a "% Symbol" to decimal value in C#. Here is my code.

So my question is, is there any way I can assign a "%" symbol to `BRCList[l].TotalDifference.Value`. `BRCList[l].TotalDifference.Value` is decimal type from the service side.

I need to append "%" symbol:

```
string TotalDifference = string.Empty;
if (Type == "P")
{
    TotalDifference = String.Format("{0:0.##}", BRCList[l].TotalDifference.Value) + "%";
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand where your issue lies. What should the final string look like? This looks like it already appends a `%` to the string.

Comment: You kind of answered your own question: "if(Type == "P")"....  use the ['P' format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier) like: 'string.Format("{0:P2}")' ...

Comment: I basically wants to append the "%" symbol to decimal values , final decimal value should looks like : 20% or 30% etc... what ever the decimal values comes append the % at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign an appended character to a base numeric type.  The only way would be to first convert it to a string like you do in the code above.

The other option would be to box it in a custom struct that knows it's a percentage stored as a decimal.  Then you could override that struct's ToString method to always automatically append the percentage sign, but you'd also probably need to override all the logical and arithmetic operators that decimal normally supports to maintain any sort of compatibility.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response